# Joining objects in Three.js with lines

Tags: geometry, three.js

When I am trying to use :
var arrow = new THREE.ArrowHelper(direction, startPoint, startPoint.distanceTo(endPoint), 0xCC0000 );
scene.add(arrow);

it basically uses a point rather than an object. Does anyone know how to join to objects directly in three.js?

Comment: I think your question is far too open ended to provide feedback. Try and give us some idea of what your trying to do, what you've already tried, and maybe you'll have better results. For example: Are you asking about getting a point from an object to use for your use case? Are you looking to merge the geometry of two or more objects? Are you looking to join to objects via a parent object group? Anyway, hope you can sort it out.

Comment: Hi Darryl, I am trying to join objects with lines in three.js.  Suppose we have two spheres then I need to join them both with a line . Also if I try to drag any of the sphere the line should also extend or compress based on the movement.  Iam trying to do something like this : http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/dynamicAnchors/jquery.html  but in 3d using three.js

Comment: Just noticed you have 2 other questions about the same thing on Stackoverflow. This is not recommended, I suggest you have a look at the posting rules, specifically [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Okay without code to plug into I'll provide the steps in Pseudo code:

1) Create 2 `THREE.SphereGeometry`, matching Materials, apply them to a `THREE.Mesh` aptly named.

2) Store a point from each Sphere via: `sphere1.geometry.vertices[0]` or whatever point index you feel works best.

3) Use those points to build your `THREE.ArrowHelper`

That should get you going. Of course the next steps look something like this:

4) Detect user intersect with each Sphere (look up Raycaster example)

5) Build move logic to reposition your Sphere

6) Update the scene objects to reflect the new positions

Hope that helps,

D

Comment: The sphere1.geometry.vertices[0] gives the index not the actual position. My exact question is how do i bind an arrow to two objects. I modified the "webgl_interactive_draggablecubes.html" to have only 2 cubes.

Comment: The extra changes that I made are: var sourcePos = new THREE.Vector3(objects[0].position.x, objects[0].position.y, objects[0].position.z);
var targetPos = new THREE.Vector3(objects[1].position.x, objects[1].position.y, objects[1].position.z);
var direction = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(targetPos, sourcePos);
var arrow = new THREE.ArrowHelper(direction.clone().normalize(), sourcePos, direction.length(), 0xff0000);
scene.add( arrow );  But this does not bind the arrow to any of the cubes. When I drag the cube arrow is staying in its original position.

Comment: Good day, indeed my steps above are pseudo code, so you do need to fill in the blanks where needed. Please read my original post, you must create the "binding" yourself. Research the topics I've set forth and you'll be fine. Stackoverflow is about helping solve problems, not a rent a coder site. If you have a complete set of code, post it up and we can start from there.